# Execute PHP via WP Short code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, caching, dynamic, shortcode

I have a PHP code snippet (WP Short code) to display a banner when a YouTube channel is live. As a result, I need the PHP to run quite frequently (preferrably each time a user loads a webpage the PHP is invoked on, if that's not crazy)

The PHP:

```
$ytchannelID = "[YT Channel ID here";

$ytliveurl = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/".$ytchannelID."/live";

$ytchannelLIVE = '"isLive":true';

$contents = file_get_contents($ytliveurl);

$start = strpos($contents, '<meta name="title" content="') + 28;

$length = strpos($contents, '"><meta name="description" content="') - $start;

$src = substr($contents, $start, $length);

if ( strpos($contents, $ytchannelLIVE) !== false ){echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen"> * { margin: 0; padding: 0; } div#banner { top: 0; left: 0; background-color: #FFFF00; width: 100%; } div#banner-content { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center; font-family: "Permanent Marker"; } </style> <div id="banner"> <div id="banner-content">  Channel is live!  <a href="[watch url here]" style="color: #000FFF;">Tune in now: ' . $src . '</a></div> </div>';} else {echo '<div id="banner"> <div id="banner-content"></div> </div>';}
unset($ytliveurl);
```

This PHP works fine, but I have to disable page caching, or the live banner persists, or simply won't show when the channel is live because the output html is cached and not the server-side PHP. My idea, if it could work, is cache-able JavaScript that could call the PHP function by its short code. The shortcode has no input parameters, so I just need something that would simply invoke the function, like do_shortcode('[wpcode id="1238"]`).

Is something like this possible? If so, should it be done, and how?

The only example I could find similar to this seemed to use PHP, but that doesn't fit my use case since I need the solution to display the banner / hide the banner even when the page is cached. Essentially dynamic content on an otherwise cached static page.

Comment: _"preferrably each time a user loads a webpage the PHP is invoked on, if that's not crazy"_ - it is crazy, especially the way you are currently doing it: By scraping the YT frontend. You can probably expect your server IP to get blocked by YouTube, after you done this for a while. If anything, this should be done by using an appropriate API. But not on every single page load either - should look into WP Transients, to store the API call result at least for a little while.

Comment: _"Is something like this possible?"_ - you'd still need to make a request to _something_, that would execute this shortcode in the first place. Would make much more sense IMHO, if you created a custom Rest API endpoint, https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/ Then the functionality doesn't need "wrapping" into a shortcode any more to begin with either.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. I'll look into this. One of my pages uses a plugin to display the last several videos from the YT channel, and switches to the live video when the channel is live. Would it be any less crazy to employ my existing method to scrape my own page to see if a live video is up or not?

Comment: Can't tell whether you _could_ determine that "from your own page", we don't know if your plugin outputs anything different in the base HTML structure, based on whether a video is live or not.

Comment: Right, I'm going to compare "live" and "non-live" versions of the html to see if there are any differences I can scrape and use to trigger the banner message. And, I understand that's probably a big IF, but assuming there is some consistent difference I can rely on; should I? Or would this method be vastly more inefficient than what you were suggesting? I'd like the banner to be fairly timely, ideally displaying within at least 1-5 minutes of going live and not displaying at least within 1-5 minutes of a stream ending.

Comment: I would first of all check, if the existing functionality of the plugin itself can't be used, to determine this information. If the plugin is able to "switch to the live video", as you say - then _it_ must be able to determine the status somehow to begin with. Probably via API calls in the background already, I would imagine. And maybe it already provides functions you can call for that purpose ...?